# Why rkhunter skips empty and missing log file scans?

Tags: rkhunter

I have noticed that when scanning my machine with:

```
sudo rkhunter --checkall --sk
```

That part of the output in the log file is:

```
[21:50:51]   Checking for missing log files                  [ Skipped ]
[21:50:51]   Checking for empty log files                    [ Skipped ]
[21:50:51]
[21:50:51] Info: Test 'apps' disabled at users request.
```

Why are some of these test skipped? And how would I get it not to skip them? Also what does it mean by `Test 'apps' disabled at users request`, as I have not asked it to not test for anything?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
rkhunter:
  Installed: 1.4.0-3
  Candidate: 1.4.0-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.0-3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, according to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/rkhunter.8.html) `--checkall` is not a valid command. Probably `rkhunter` interprets it as just `--check`.

---

The checking for missing and empty log files are performed by the *filesystem* test. Both are user defined checks; you must tell `rkhunter` which log files it is suppose to check. This is the relevant part of `/etc/rkhunter.conf`:

```
# The two options below may be used to check if a file is missing or empty
# (that is, it has a size of zero). The EMPTY_LOGFILES option will also check
# if the file is missing, since that can be interpreted as a file of no size.
# However, the file will only be reported as missing if the MISSING_LOGFILES
# option hasn't already done this.
#
# Both options are space-separated lists of pathnames, and may be specified
# more than once.
#
# NOTE: Log files are usually 'rotated' by some mechanism. At that time it is
# perfectly possible for the file to be either missing or empty. As such these
# options may produce false-positive warnings when log files are rotated.
#
# For both options the default value is the null string.
#
#EMPTY_LOGFILES=""
#MISSING_LOGFILES=""
```

I think it is self explanatory.

---

Regarding the `Test 'apps' disabled at users request` info message, the answer is also in `/etc/rkhunter.conf`. This is where you should look:

```
# These two options determine which tests are to be performed. The ENABLE_TESTS
# option can use the word 'ALL' to refer to all of the available tests. The
# DISABLE_TESTS option can use the word 'NONE' to mean that no tests are
# disabled. The list of disabled tests is applied to the list of enabled tests.
#
# Both options are space-separated lists of test names, and both options may
# be specified more than once. The currently available test names can be seen
# by using the command 'rkhunter --list tests'.
#
# The supplied configuration file has some tests already disabled, and these
# are tests that will be used only occasionally, can be considered 'advanced'
# or that are prone to produce more than the average number of false-positives.
#
# Please read the README file for more details about enabling and disabling
# tests, the test names, and how rkhunter behaves when these options are used.
#
# The default values are to enable all tests and to disable none. However, if
# either of the options below are specified, then they will override the
# program defaults.
#
# hidden_procs test requires the unhide and/or unhide.rb commands which are
# part of the unhide respectively unhide.rb packages in Debian.
#
# apps test is disabled by default as it triggers warnings about outdated
# applications (and warns about possible security risk: we better trust
# the Debian Security Team).
#
ENABLE_TESTS=ALL
DISABLE_TESTS=suspscan hidden_procs deleted_files packet_cap_apps apps
```

You could remove from `DISABLE_TESTS` the name of the test you want to run or replace all of them with `NONE`, if you really want to run all the tests. Alternatively, you could tell `rkhunter` to run all the tests with:

```
sudo rkhunter --sk --enable all --disable none
```